# getting the metrics of an endpoint

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have an endpoint of my API, now I want to track that whenever a request is being made to my endpoint then how many were returning 200 and how many were returning 400 or other HTTP status code please advise how can I achieve the same in spring boot project, I am using spring boot actuators 2.

Suppose my endpoint is:

```
https://localhost:9090/users
```

So what I want is:

```
{  
    "404": 1,
    "200": 6,
    "409": 1
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I recommend providing more information about your setup, problem and a miminal, reproducable example.

Comment: Hello, go through my answer below and let me the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/actuator/metrics/` to get all endPoints which are executed/called with their  *count, exception, outcome, status, total time, etc.* For this case *count, status* is useful

For that, you have to add a dependency in pom.xml or similar in grade

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

[Get Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator)

---

*To get details of `all endPoint` which are executed/called (see outcome all endPoint)*

```
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests
```

---

*To get details of `particular endPoint` (see outcome particular
   endPoint)*

```
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:<endPoint>
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/users
```

---

*To get the count of particular endPoint with Status Code (see outcome
   particular endPoint with Status code)*

```
localhost:8889/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests?tag=uri:/users&tag=status:200
```

---

*outcome all endPoint*

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 13
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.42338
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "uri",
            "values": [
                "/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
                "/getCountByStatus"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "404",
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

*see outcome particular endPoint*

```
{
    "name": "http.server.requests",
    "description": null,
    "baseUnit": "seconds",
    "measurements": [
        {
            "statistic": "COUNT",
            "value": 5
        },
        {
            "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
            "value": 0.1830878
        },
        {
            "statistic": "MAX",
            "value": 0
        }
    ],
    "availableTags": [
        {
            "tag": "exception",
            "values": [
                "None"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "method",
            "values": [
                "GET"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "outcome",
            "values": [
                "CLIENT_ERROR",
                "SUCCESS"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tag": "status",
            "values": [
                "404",
                "200"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

*outcome particular endPoint with Status code*

```
 {
        "name": "http.server.requests",
        "description": null,
        "baseUnit": "seconds",
        "measurements": [
            {
                "statistic": "COUNT",
                "value": 3
            },
            {
                "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
                "value": 0.034849
            },
            {
                "statistic": "MAX",
                "value": 0
            }
        ],
        "availableTags": [
            {
                "tag": "exception",
                "values": [
                    "None"
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "method",
                "values": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "outcome",
                "values": [
                    "SUCCESS"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Configure Spring boot actuator dependencies in your pom.xml file.

The metrics you required can be accessible by this endpoint `localhost:8080/actuato/metrics`

It will contains statistics like threads, heap memory, remaining memory etc.

For your case these two keys in that JSON response will be useful.

**Guage and counter**

**Guage** - will gives each API response time.

**Counter** - this will full fill your requirement like `{
 200:4,
400:1
}`

Explaination :
 Your API returns 200 status code 4 times and 400 status code 1 time.